# -gt: unary operator expected shell script

Tags: command-line, bash

Getting this error after the upgrade packages in ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash
used=$(df -H | grep  'rootfs' | cut -d "G" -f 4 | cut -d "%" -f 1)
limit=90
if [ $used -gt $limit ]; then Or [ "$used" -gt "$limit" ] Or [ "$used" -ge 90 ]
#delete file and mail command;
fi
```

Error

> [: -gt: unary operator expected

Answer (score 5):

The variable `used` is empty, leading to the error message regarding unary operator. Possible reason could be there is no `rootfs` in `df -H` output i.e. in your system.

```
$ foo=
$ [ $foo -gt 10 ] && echo OK
bash: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

---

You have also some other issues in your script, the OR logic should be put as:

```
[ "$foo" -gt "$bar" ] || [ "$foo" -ge 90 ]
```

Also better use the shell keywod `[[` instead of `test` (`[`) command to avoid many pitfalls:

```
[[ "$foo" -gt "$bar" ]] || [[ "$foo" -ge 90 ]]
```

For arithmetic comparisons, you can also use `((` and regular arithmetic operators:

```
(( "$foo" > "$bar" )) || (( "$foo" >= 90 ))
```

You don't even need to put `$` in-front of the variable name:

```
(( foo > bar )) || (( foo >= 90 ))
```